# How get multiple values from checkbox list into state using React useState hook

Tags: reactjs, forms, checkbox, use-state

How do I set multiple values (from my mapped checkboxes) to the state using React `useState` hook?

When I log `selectedValue`  it shows only the last selected option? I need all selected values when submitting the form.

```
const MyComponent = ({ options }: Props) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState({});

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSelectedValue({ ...selectedValue, [e.target.value]: e.target.value      
   });
console.warn(selectedValue);

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <ul>
          {options.map(({ id, label }) => (
            <li key={id}>
              <label htmlFor={label}>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
                  }}
                  value={id}
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                {` Checkbox ${label}`}
              </label>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Here's how you can achieve it, refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60461571

Answer (score 0):

For saving multiple things of something prefer arrays instead objects.

In this case, your gonna need to use an array instead of object in your default useState:

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);
```

And in `onChange` function:

```
onChange={(e) => {
   setSelectedValue([...selectedValue, e.target.value]);
 }}
```